# Python string operations to generate date format

Tags: python, pandas, string

I am using the below code to generate a variable that can be used in my code:
value of `year_current is 21`

Code:

```
month_1 = "Jan '"
month_2 = "Dec '"
'"' + month_1 + str(year_current) + '":"' +month_2 + str(year_current) + '"'
```

The output generated by the above code is :

```
"Jan \'21":"Dec \'21"
```

I do not want the "" symbol in the output. What can be done to avoid that?

Expected output:

```
"Jan '21":"Dec '21" (with all the quotes intact so that I can use this in df.loc)
```

I have also used the below approach:

Code:

```
month_1 = "'Jan '"
month_2 = ":'Dec '"
month_1 +str(year_current)+"'" +month_2 +str(year_current)+"'"
```

This gives me the output:

```
'Jan '21':'Dec '21'
```

But then it creates confusion in the code with respect to single quotes. Hence this does not work for me.

Not sure if its due to my code being in Jupyter but solution is not working as expected:

[image]

Comment: @Downvote: Why the downvote? Please explain so that I can improve in future.

Answer (score 1):

In this case you could use `f-string`.

**Try this:**

```
month_1 = "Jan '"
month_2 = "Dec '"
year_current = 21
#year_current = pd.Timestamp.today().strftime('%y') #if you dont want hardcord year

month_str = f'"{month_1}{year_current}":"{month_2}{year_current}"'

print(month_str)
```

**Output:**

```
"Jan '21":"Dec '21"
```

Comment: the print will show the output without a backward slash. But when I use the month_str variable in the code, it will contain "\"

Comment: could you please share the code that you are working so that we can test too?

Comment: I just removed the print statement from your answer. please check the value of month_str without the print statement.

Comment: could you try my updated answer?

Comment: i posted the screenshot in the question above. Not sure if it's due to Jupyter notebook.

Comment: It seems because of jupyter notebook